# Android Crashlytics plugin not installing library

Tags: android, crashlytics

When using the Crashlytics plugin in intellij I follow these steps.

1. Click plugin on toolbar.
2. Select App
3. Allow crashlytics to update AndroidManifest.xml as well has my first Activity.
   [image]
4. Click "Next"
5. Try to build the App as the plugin instructs.
   [image]

Then when i try to build i get this:

package com.crashlytics.android does not exist
[image]

I look in my dependencies and library and the jar is nowhere to be found.
What am I missing that would cause the library to not be loaded?

Comment: have you found a solution yet? I am running into the same problem

Comment: Nope. I've been in contact with crashlytics. They didn't have a solution right off the bat, so they are "looking into it"

Comment: Well I found that the problem lies in my build.gradle file. After following https://crashlytics.com/downloads/gradle it all worked!

Comment: I'm not using gradle. However, they gave me the library jar until they could find a solution. So its fixed for me too.

Comment: ran into the same problem, just restarted IntelliJ and repeating the process a couple of times eventually added the necessary Jar to the libs folder and dependencies ... to be honest copy+pasting 3 lines and adding a jar would have been way easier.

Comment: @Su-AuHwang I agree. Though, via their plugin they have control of updates....so I can see why they did it, but still i shouldnt of had to spend hours trying to get it to work when 3 lines of code would have done the trick

Comment: @KentAndersen i stand corrected, apparently the plugin does some more work (during build time?). Not even sure what it is, probably magic. Would be nice to know what it is actually doing.

Comment: @KentAndersen  If you are not using Gradle, it will be hard to manage dependencies in Android Studio.  It would be easier to follow the link Ruben Weerts provided and just set it up the modern way.

Comment: At the time i wasn't using android studio. I was using intellij.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following configuration should work for Gradle-based projects:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://download.crashlytics.com/maven" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+"
    }
}
apply plugin: "crashlytics"
repositories {
    maven { url "http://download.crashlytics.com/maven" }
}
dependencies {
    compile "com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.1.+"
}
```

Taken from https://crashlytics.com/downloads/gradle

Comment: Way back when i posted the question, this wasn't even an option. But today, this is the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by following the maven instructions here https://crashlytics.com/downloads/maven and then just grabbing the jar from my .m2 and putting it in my libs folder. (This particular project was started as a maven project, then Maven was discarded and it has not yet been migrated to Gradle, so we're kind of in no-man's land). Anyway, I now have the jar.

Answer (score 1):

After the automated setup from android studio, I was missing this line:

`compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.1.+'`